# Items missing from LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

We are looking to resolve 2 issues we are experiencing with the API we are using.
Since we upgraded to the new API, the feed no longer includes:

1. Profile headline
2. Original profile picture

How can I get these?

Also when we use Linkedin Social Sign On. Users see a message that says:
"[our business] would like to post, comment and like posts on your behalf".

We do not wish to post, comment and like posts on our customers behalf.

Is there a way to remove this messaging?

Comment: According to [LinkedIn API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin) the user profile picture should be included in the response.

Answer (score 1):

> [our business] would like to post, comment and like posts on your behalf

The permission scope associated with this message is **w_member_social**. If you do not need this permission, remove it from the **scope** parameter in your requests to retrieve an access token.